# what is the mechanism that set uses to find duplicate values?

Tags: java, collections, duplicates, set

in my last the interview they ask me this question and I wonder what is the answer?
can someone help me please
what is the strategy that set uses to find duplicate values in java?

Comment: That depends on implementation. Are you asking about HashSet or TreeSet or maybe some other Set implementation?

Comment: @Pshemo - agreed; the general answer is that a Set mush check whether it already has an instance of the value, and that the 'check' depends on the data structure chosen;  but presumably the interviewer had a particular implementation in mind.  In which case the correct interviewee response would be "which implementation should I describe?".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about another languages but in java set/hashset internally uses hashmap.
And whenever add method is called on set the value is searched in hashmap using the hash if the value is present the add method returns false i.e value is not added to set. And if the value is not present in the map then it is added to set.

Comment: HashSet is not the only Set in Java.